# will ros-dynamixel support dynamixel pro servos?

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there seem to be some differences in the protocol

see

http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel_pro/communication/instruction_status_packet.htm

and

http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel/communication/dxl_packet.htm

however, on the dynamixel pro communication site robotis states

> Dynamixel protocol 2.0
> Previously both Dynamixel and Dynamixel PRO implemented a different protocol. TO verify protocol version please refer to both instruction and status packet.

unfortunately i couldn't find any information if the ros-dynamixel package will support the pro servos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94316/will-ros-dynamixel-support-dynamixel-pro-servos?/) by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2013-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on 2013-10-25**:
so by looking at the code i figured out that they are currently not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i emailed the package maintainer.

he does not have access to a dymixel pro servo. since they use a quite different protocol the pro series is not supported currently and it's unclear when they can add support for it.

---

Originally posted by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) with karma: 48 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1